# Print to file from within a method

Tags: java, printing, expression, bufferedwriter, infix-notation

I am taking an input file with various infix expressions, calculating them, and printing them back to another output file with each line formatted as:

*THE MODULO 10 VALUE OF %%%%% IS %*

The output text and modulo 10 answer are both correct; however, I cannot get the program to reprint the entire expression in between "OF" and "IS."

I tried putting `output.write(token)` in the getToken() method, but I got a "cannot find symbol" error. So I understand that I can't access the BufferedWriter from another method since it is declared in main, but how can I get around that?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Lab1
{
public static char token;
public static String expr;
public static int k = 0;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int exprValue;
    String line;

    try
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputfile.txt"));
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile.txt"));

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {               
            output.write("THE MODULO 10 VALUE OF ");
            expr = line;
            getToken();             
            output.write(token);
            exprValue = expression();
            output.write(" IS " + exprValue);
            output.newLine();               
            output.newLine();               
            k = 0;
        }

        input.close();
        output.close();

    }

    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Exception:" + ex);
    }

}

public static void getToken()
{
    k++;

    int count = k-1;

    if(count < expr.length())
    {
        token = expr.charAt(count);
    }
}

public static int expression()
{
    int termValue;
    int exprValue;

    exprValue = term();

    while(token == '+')
    {
        getToken();
        termValue = term();
        exprValue = (exprValue + termValue)%10;
    }

    return exprValue;
}

public static int factor()
{
    int factorValue = token;

    if(Character.isDigit(token))
    {
        factorValue = Character.getNumericValue(token);
        getToken();
    }
    else if(token == '(')
    {
        getToken();
        factorValue = expression();

        if(token == ')')
        {
            getToken();
        }
    }

    return factorValue;
}

public static int term()
{
    int factorValue;
    int termValue;

    termValue = factor();
    while(token == '*')
    {
        getToken();
        factorValue = factor();
        termValue = (termValue * factorValue)%10;
    }

    return termValue;
}
}
```

Currently my input is:

(3*6+4)*(4+5*7)

3*((4+5*(1+6)+2))

My output is:

THE MODULO 10 VALUE OF ( IS 8

THE MODULO 10 VALUE OF 3 IS 3

Comment: After further investigation, I'm fairly certain that putting `output.write(token)` inside the getToken() method will solve my problem, but how can I do that?

Comment: Solved the problem. In the while loop in the main method, replace `output.write(token)` with `output.write(expr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. In the while loop in the main method, replace `output.write(token)` with `output.write(expr)`